# 7zip commandline equivalent of these gui settings?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I'm trying to compress an archive using the following GUI settings: 7z, Fastest, LZMA2, Dict 64KB, Word 32, solid block 8mb, cpu threads 8.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m1=lzma2:d64k:fb32:son8m -ms=8m -mmt=8 -r -y data2.zip data*
```

The performance is no where near the GUI. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
7z a data2.7z -mx1 -m0=lzma2 data*
```